# Is there a way too simulate a wired connection too the router using wireless?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Essentially trick the router into thinking I'm connected to it via cable. 
I only have access to the router configuration with an Ethernet connection hence the question, this is not a blocker at all but I would like to access it with a wireless connection.

Changing the router configs to allow wireless connections is not an option.

EDIT: After some research I'm almost sure there's no way to do this as I expected. Anyway for this purpose rcpa0 answer is a possible solution.

Comment: You shouldn't need to 'trick' it. Many routers have a switch for access/block admin configuration over wifi. Blocking is for better security, of course, because anyone trying to access the admin pages would need to already be in the building.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a wireless bridge or powerline ethernet extender both I'm guessing you don't want to use since it requires additional hardware. I'm fairly confident there is no 'tricking' your router for something like this if you can't access its configuration via Wi-Fi. Please edit your question to give us the router model & fixes you've attempted. Many consumer routers have a 'Guest' Wi-Fi which I'm guessing might deliberately disable access to the routers configuration so be sure you're not on the Guest SSID/network

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a proxy/port forwarder on a system that is wired to the WiFi router.  SSH tunnel or use Wireless client to VNC / Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) server to WiFi router's configuration web interface.  Raspberry Pi + VNC or SSH tunnel if you need a cheap, always on, stand alone server solution.
2. Add another WiFi router on the same wired network with a different SSID and disabling the DHCP server on it (there can only be one DHCP server on a network).  You could manage each WiFi router while connected from the other.